# Use of unresolved identifier 'UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect' in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to create a text field by code in swift, here is snippet of my code:

```
let hiddenTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.size.height - 30, 50, 10))
hiddenTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect
```

Problem is - I am getting this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect'

***Note:*** I am doing this in subclass of SKScene

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of the transition to a more flexible language, some of the Swift Cocoa APIs are tweaked from their Objective-C counterparts. You'll definitely notice then when dealing with enums—Swift enums are much more powerful and extensible. What you're looking for is the `RoundedRect` case of the `UITextBorderStyle` enum type, which can even be inferred from the left-hand side:

```
hiddenTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
```

I'll refer you to the [Swift enum documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_223), since Swift enums are significantly different from most other languages. You can also create [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_229) on enums.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer:

```
hiddenTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
```

:)

Comment: Even better would be `hiddenTextField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect`, because Swift can infer the type of the enum from `borderStyle`!

Comment: Added it, with a little background story :P